Azure devops throwing stderr: 'fatal: You are not currently on a branch.' when trying to push the code to checked out branch using GitPython library
I am trying to check out a git branch,generate files using python code and then push the changes to the branch using GitPython library
Below is the code used
repo = git.Repo(build_agent_artifact_directory)

branch_name =  source_branch_name.split('/')[-1]
if branch_name in repo.branches:
   repo.git.checkout(branch_name)

**Python code to generate files and add it to the remote location**

repo.git.add('--all')
repo.index.commit("pushing generated files")
origin = repo.remote(name='origin')
origin.push()

Getting below error when script is executed.
git.exc.GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(128)
cmdline: git push --porcelain origin
stderr: 'fatal: You are not currently on a branch.'

Are you on detached HEAD state at the moment?

@eftshift0 I am supposed to be in the branch as I am checking out using the code "repo.git.checkout(branch_name)". But getting not on a branch error.

What does git status say?

@eftshift0 repo.git.status() gives below message.
"On branch feature_acc_test1
nothing to commit, working tree clean"

Have you copied the files generated using python code to the local folder of your repo?

It seems that it doesn't checkout your target branch successfully. To check whether one branch exists in your remote repo, you can use references. Refer to the example below.
build_agent_artifact_directory = "{The path to your local repo}"
branch_name = "BranchA"

# Initialize the repository
repo = git.Repo(build_agent_artifact_directory)

ref_name = "origin/"+ branch_name
# Checkout target branch if it exists
for ref in repo.references:
    if ref_name == ref.name:
        print(f"Checkout: {branch_name}")
        repo.git.checkout(branch_name)

# Python code to generate files and add it to the remote location**
if branch_name == repo.active_branch.name:
    with open('test.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write('Hi\n')
    shutil.copy('test.txt', '{repo folder}/test.txt')
    repo.index.add('test.txt')

# Add all changes to the staging area
repo.git.add('--all')

# Commit the changes
repo.index.commit("pushing generated files")

# Push the changes to the remote repository
origin = repo.remote(name='origin')
origin.push()

